# How to change Area Admin

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

this is a client requirement , he do not want the admin panel to be look like `www.abc.com/admin/..`, but want as `www.abc.com/eSales/` we did change on `adminAreaRegistration` page accordingly , but problem start from plugin, currently  `CountryState` tax plugin causing issue

```
.../eSales/Tax/ConfigureProvider?systemName=Tax.CountryStateZip
```

No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No route in the
>   route table matches the supplied values.

Source Error:

```
Line 12: @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ConfigurationActionName))
Line 13: {
Line 14:     @Html.Action(Model.ConfigurationActionName, Model.ConfigurationControllerName, Model.ConfigurationRouteValues);
Line 15: }
Line 16: else
```

Now Question is How is it change the "admin" ?  what we are missing ?files are there and as mapped in Nop , i means plugin are build on the Plugin folder along with the name in nop.web/Plugins folder, and also Plugins[Projects for plugin] folder is in same as we get with Nop download.

in other word i checked it it is following same thing as told in 
http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/77/how-to-write-a-nopcommerce-plugin.aspx

and interesting thing is when i am running RAW NOP and debugging values in the parameters are looks same.

What the issue ?

Few more things i found

1. i am using nop 3.00 [nopCommerce_3.00_Source ]
2. In case or original source control flow going in this way after i click on the configuration link of Tax.CountryStateZip  on page Admin/Tax/Providers

---

1 - 
    nopCommerce_3.00_Source\Presentation\Nop.Web\Administration\Views\Tax\ConfigureProvider.cshtml

```
@Html.Action(Model.ConfigurationActionName, Model.ConfigurationControllerName, Model.ConfigurationRouteValues);
```

then

---

2 -

```
nopCommerce_3.00_Source\Presentation\Nop.Web.Framework\Localization\LocalizedRoute.cs

public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
```

here it's looping for lot's of times and all time `data=null`,

---

then

```
nopCommerce_3.00_Source\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Tax.CountryStateZip\Controllers\TaxCountryStateZipController.cs

protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
```

Now if you consider my part, my `admin=eSales` all are same value except the area, i have check with break point , but after 2nd step i am getting error

```
"No route in the route table matches the supplied values."
```

and control flow stop, i am not finding why ? is anything hard coded with "Admin" word any where i need to change?

It will be great if you can help me to resolve it , i am not too much old in Nop so may be some little mistake causing this issue ,

**and interestingly** i found all configuration base plugin getting same issue `admin/plugin` page i have check

Comment: Guys anything ? any help or clue ?

Comment: Till now , nothing :(

Comment: Dont know, if it is too late. but there are no routes specifid for admin side , but you can specify routes for this one

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Tax.CountryStateZip is routing to the admin ... so if you going to change the AdminAreaRegistration and name it with different name, you have to modify all the plugins that is routing to the admin area ... for example if you want the Tax.CountryStateZip to work .. you have to replace the area in the below route:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.AddCountryId)").change(function() {
       var selectedItem = $(this).val();
       var ddlStates = $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.AddStateProvinceId)");
       $.ajax({
           cache: false,
           type: "GET",
           url: "@(Url.Action("GetStatesByCountryId", "Country", new RouteValueDictionary() { { "area", "**Admin**" } }))",
           data: { "countryId": selectedItem, "addAsterisk": "true" },
           success: function(data) {
               ddlStates.html('');
               $.each(data, function(id, option) {
                   ddlStates.append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));
               });
           },
           error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               alert('Failed to retrieve states.');
           }
       });
   });
});
```

and to replace it with the name you wish like that:

```
url: "@(Url.Action("GetStatesByCountryId", "Country", new RouteValueDictionary() { { "area", "**YOUR_NEW_ADMIN_AREA_NAME**" } }))",
```

and so all the plugins which is routing the area="admin"

and after that your have to recompile the nopCommerce project